# Custom form for many to many relationships in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-admin

Let's say I have a simple model of the city and streets

```
class City(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)

class Street(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'streets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
```

and relation model

```
db.Table('city_street',
        db.Column('city_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('cities.id')),
        db.Column('street_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('streets.id')))
```

I want to link the city and streets on edit city page. But I do not want to use standard multiselect (**select2**). I need to display on the edit page the list of all the streets (in my case, they will not be much), and manually associate streets with this city. This can be a normal **checkbox** or something similar.

I want to list items could be easily customizable and extensible. With the ability to add descriptions of elements, images.

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8wPO.png)

I was considering as an option **InlineFormField**, but there may be added to the model only one entry, and would like to see all the records at once and choose from them simply by clicking on the record.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done, perhaps by writing custom form?

Comment: You could populate the usual select2 by overriding create_form. This way, you'll have all your street iin the field and you juste have to remove the one you don't want